# why can't I use the same javascript toggle button twice?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'm attempting to utilize this javascript toggle button in two separate parts on the same page, but I'm having trouble. I tried altering the id as well, but it didn't work. Is it impossible to complete it, or am I overlooking something? I am not an expert in javascript and am a complete novice, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function toggleText() {
  var showMoreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var buttonText   = document.querySelector("#moreButton span");
  var moreIcon     = document.querySelector("#moreButton img");

  if (startpoint.style.display === "none") {
    showMoreText.style.display = "none";
    startpoint.style.display = "table-cell";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show More";
    buttonText.classList.remove('less');
    moreIcon.classList.remove('less');
  } else {
    showMoreText.style.display = "table-cell";
    startpoint.style.display = "none";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    buttonText.classList.add('less');
    moreIcon.classList.add('less');
  }
}

function toggleText2() {
  var showMoreText2 = document.getElementById("more2");
  var buttonText2   = document.querySelector("#moreButton2 span");
  var moreIcon2     = document.querySelector("#moreButton2 img");

  if (startpoint.style.display === "none") {
    showMoreText.style.display = "none";
    startpoint.style.display = "table-cell";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show More";
    buttonText.classList.remove('less2');
    moreIcon.classList.remove('less2');
  } else {
    showMoreText.style.display = "table-cell";
    startpoint.style.display = "none";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    buttonText.classList.add('less2');
    moreIcon.classList.add('less2');
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid clientbox text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>

    <div id="startpoint"></div>
    <div id="more">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class=" col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="toggleText()" id="moreButton">
            <span class="pink">Show More</span> 
            <img class="more" src="./images/load-more.png" alt="">
            </button>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container-fluid clientbox text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>

    <div id="startpoint2"></div>
    <div id="more2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class=" col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="toggleText2()" id="moreButton2">
            <span class="pink2">Show More</span> 
            <img class="more2" src="./images/load-more.png" alt="">
            </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please update the code you've provided to meet the standards of creating a [mre]? Currently, there's a seemingly unrelated error being thrown by your snippet regarding the variable `showMoreText` not being properly defined.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer your question, but you can definitely use the same JS function multiple times (a button with the same `onclick` event). The idea is to make your selectors less specific. Think about using the JS nextElementSibling: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling

Comment: @j08691 but i am using different id's

Comment: You have two `id="moreButton"`

Comment: @j08691 i fixed it and still not working :/

Comment: You renamed the variables in `toggleText2`, but didn't change the users of those variables so it gets an error. But there's not really a need to rename the variables, since they're local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some issues with the naming of your variables etc. (things coming up as undefined).

```js
function toggleText() {
  var showMoreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var buttonText   = document.querySelector("#moreButton span");
  var moreIcon     = document.querySelector("#moreButton img");

  if (startpoint.style.display === "none") {
    showMoreText.style.display = "none";
    startpoint.style.display = "table-cell";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show More";
    buttonText.classList.remove('less');
    moreIcon.classList.remove('less');
  } else {
    showMoreText.style.display = "table-cell";
    startpoint.style.display = "none";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    buttonText.classList.add('less');
    moreIcon.classList.add('less');
  }
}

function toggleText2() {
  var showMoreText2 = document.getElementById("more2");
  var buttonText2   = document.querySelector("#moreButton2 span");
  var moreIcon2     = document.querySelector("#moreButton2 img");

  if (startpoint.style.display === "none") {
    showMoreText2.style.display = "none";
    startpoint.style.display = "table-cell";
    buttonText2.innerHTML = "Show More";
    buttonText2.classList.remove('less2');
    moreIcon2.classList.remove('less2');
  } else {
    showMoreText2.style.display = "table-cell";
    startpoint.style.display = "none";
    buttonText2.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    buttonText2.classList.add('less2');
    moreIcon2.classList.add('less2');
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid clientbox text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>

    <div id="startpoint"></div>
    <div id="more">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class=" col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="toggleText()" id="moreButton">
            <span class="pink">Show More</span> 
            <img class="more" src="./images/load-more.png" alt="">
            </button>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container-fluid clientbox text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>

    <div id="startpoint2"></div>
    <div id="more2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class=" col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="toggleText2()" id="moreButton2">
            <span class="pink2">Show More</span> 
            <img class="more2" src="./images/load-more.png" alt="">
            </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

With that said, there are much cleaner ways of constructing this logic. For instance, you could parse the event and look for a certain parent or child to toggle. That way, you can utilize the same function as long as it's surrounded by the same html structure. You'd have to exchange the id's for classes however.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do that:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.moreButton').forEach(bt =>
  {
  let
    moreItem = bt.closest('div.row').querySelector('div.more_items')
  , spPink   = bt.querySelector('span.pink')
    ;
  bt.onclick =_=>
    {
    spPink.textContent = moreItem.classList.toggle('noDisplay') ? 'Show More' : 'Show Less'
    } 
  })
```

```css
.more_items.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class="container-fluid clientbox text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
  
      <div class="more_items">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="moreButton">
        <span class="pink">Show Less</span> 
        <img class="more" src="./images/load-more.png" alt="">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <div class="container-fluid clientbox text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
  
      <div class="more_items">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
          <div class=" col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/100px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="moreButton">
        <span class="pink">Show Less</span> 
        <img class="more" src="./images/load-more.png" alt="">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```